# How do I re-fetch svn:log changes in git-svn?

Tags: git, git-svn

SVN permits the ability to update an old commit message via hook. How can I go about updating my git-svn copy's version of the commit message? The only reference I could find was a bug report *requesting* this feature about a year ago on [debian.org](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=469298).

Is this possible in the current version of Git v1.6.3.*?

If not, what's the most intelligent way to go about updating the local copy? The dumbest method that occured to me was brute-force; repeating a `git svn clone` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem a few weeks ago. I wanted to re-fetch a commit sent 6 commits behind. I executed

```
git reset --hard HEAD~6
```

to remove the latest 6 commits from Git, then I fetched them again from SVN.

```
git svn rebase
```

Probably it's not the best way to solve this problem, but it was the easier solution in that moment.

Comment: Given there is no good solution, this one appears to be "best" so far. I did not know I could do that with reset. But its a recent commit so this will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

*(Not really an answer)*

You can't without *rewriting history*, shown how to do it by [weppos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/weppos) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051163/how-do-i-re-fetch-svnlog-changes-in-git-svn/1051602#1051602).
Commits in Git are immutable.

[In the future](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=8afef5cdc6c09491c366b7bb854e3953bbb28db5) you would be able to use "**[git notes](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/pu:Documentation/git-notes.txt)**" to annotate commit message.